# Track nodes to destination from origin

Tags: scala, search, queue, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I made this breadth first search algorithm in scala, and was wondering if anybody could help me with identifying what I need to have it track the shortest path of start to end node rather than just the distance. It starts by making a graph with indexes that are Ints for each grid point, and the grid locations are just x and y coordinates. Thanks! I want it to either spit out a linkedList or a regular list.

```
def bfsDistance(gameState: AIGameState, start: GridLocation, end: GridLocation):Int={
    val maze: Graph[GridLocation] = gameState.levelAsGraph()
    val startNodeIndex = maze.nodes.filter(_._2 == start).keys.head
    val endNodeIndex = maze.nodes.filter(_._2 == end).keys.head

    var distMap = Map(startNodeIndex -> 0)
    var visited = Set(startNodeIndex)
    val queue = new mutable.Queue[(Int,Int)]
    queue.enqueue((startNodeIndex, 0))

    while (!queue.isEmpty) {
      val (nodeIndex, nodeDist) = queue.dequeue()
      if (nodeIndex == endNodeIndex) {
        return distMap(nodeIndex)
      } else {
        for (neighbor <- maze.adjacencyList(nodeIndex)) {
          if (!visited.contains(neighbor)) { 
            queue.enqueue((neighbor, nodeDist+1)) 
            distMap += neighbor -> (nodeDist+1)
            visited = visited + neighbor 
          }
        }
      }
    }
    distMap(endNodeIndex)
  }
```

Comment: The Dijkstra algorithm will do this for you.

Comment: If all edges are of the same length ("cost") use BSF. Otherwise use Dijkstra algorithm, Please clarify your question. [mre] would be best.